# How avoid URL error in my code python and open the file only one time?

Tags: python, url

I would like to know how avoid the URL error in my script.and would like to know the way to open only one time the file(not two like in my code)without create an error when run it.
(actual code work)

the help could be here :

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.URLError

with "try" and "exept" ?

can you advice on this than this could work on my code ?

for the error url would like to post a message for user when it's wrong :

for exemple i change the adress :

[image]

and when run : error appear now

[image]

so i want to put like "bad URL please check" etc

+

with the change i would like it print new data on a new line without deleting the old data,like this :

[image: wanted this]
here my code :

```
#Source : http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples
import urllib2
import json
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime#set the time

try:
   wunder_url_obj = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.wunderground.com/api/8d3b5d3fa03ddb6f/conditions/weather/q/China/Beijing.json')
except:
    print 'Could not open URL'
    exit()

else:

now = datetime.now()
current_year = now.year
current_day = now.day
current_month = now.month
current_hour = now.hour
current_minute = now.minute
current_second = now.second

json_string = wunder_url_obj.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather']

#--- Open the file   + write on it ---
prev_data = open('out.csv', 'r').read()

# Add a header only if the file is empty
if prev_data == '':

  with open('out.csv','a') as f:

       header = "Datetime,current condition,Temperature,\n"

       prev_data.write(header)

       date = str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.year) + " " +                         str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)
       prev_data.write(','.join([date,weather,str(temp_f)]))
       prev_data.write('\n')
```

in my editor i tried this too ;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd try to keep your variable names different (you have two different `f`). Now for the `try: except`

```
try:
    wunder_url_obj = urllib2.urlopen(api_wunder_url_opath)
except:
    print 'Could not open URL'
    sys.exit()
```

I'm assuming that you'd want to exit on a bad URL open - but that's up to you, do what you want after the except.

You are attempting to open an already opened file (`out.csv`). Try tidying up your file read / write - maybe try using the `with` statement to keep things clean and simple:

```
#--- Open the file   + write on it ---
prev_data = open('out.csv', 'r').read()

# Add a header only if the file is empty
if prev_data == '':

    with open('out.csv','a') as f:

        header = "Datetime,current condition,Temperature,\n"

        f.write(header)

        date = str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.year) + " " + str(now.hour)       + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)
        f.write(','.join([date,weather,str(temp_f)]))
        f.write('\n')

# --- And Close the file ---
```

**Edit**

Rather than re-write your code for you, I encourage you to rethink your problem. You want to

1. Read information from an URL
2. Write that information to a file
3. Repeat (goto 1)

The important thing here is to note that we're accessing the file write in a regular order - once to write the header, and then sequentially to write the information.
Maybe a better approach would be to do something like

```
 def get_information(url):

    try:
        wunder_url_obj =         urllib2.urlopen('http://api.wunderground.com/api/8d3b5d3fa03ddb6f/conditions/weather/q/China/Beijing.json')
    except:
        print 'Could not open URL'
        return None

    now = datetime.now()
    current_year = now.year
    current_day = now.day
    current_month = now.month
    current_hour = now.hour
    current_minute = now.minute
    current_second = now.second

    json_string = wunder_url_obj.read()
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
    temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
    weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather']

    date = str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.year) + " " + str(now.hour)       + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)

    return ','.join([date, weather, str(temp_f)]) + '\n'
```

so this function can be called over and over again and will return a line for your csv file each time. Then just call it and write to file;

```
 with open(my_csv_file, 'w') as fo:

      fo.write(header)

      for i in range(10):  # or whatever time scale you have

           fo.write(get_information(my_url))
```

Comment: Hi danodonovan, thanks for the reply,i did make the changes and seem to work perfectly exept one things : before i print the header one time and the data after each time under the old data, now it replace the data without print again,i would like everytime it run it print under the old data like this(i uptade my post in 30 sec for you to see)

Comment: Your post hasn't got any indentation - I hope that's just a posting error (indentation is important in python)

Comment: yes in my code all fine indentation are respected .of course it not indent all not works ^^i can post the indent if needed

Comment: ow i see what you mean! i understand now,some information i didn't thought about this.damn brain.I will try this way to do it.Thanks.will post again for confirmation.

Comment: ow it print nothing with this solution.i mean it don't create the file,nothing happened.i post my code in my post (ps : i start python 1 month ago)

Comment: In your screen shot you have included the `with open...` inside the `get_information` function - don't do that, un-indent it so that is called when the file is run.